# EntityFieldQuery with Workflow

Tags: entities, workflows

I need to filter an [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) with a given workflow state, let's say workflow it is state 21 (`sid = 21`). Below, the query I am using

```
$query_formularios_completos = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query_formularios_completos
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', array(
        'evento_agencia',
        'evento_energia'
      )
    )
    ->propertyCondition('workflow', 21)
    ->fieldCondition('field_e_expositor', 'target_id', $node_expositor_nid);
  $result_formularios_completos = $query_formularios_completos->execute();
```

When using [DEVEL](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to inspect my node, I can see there is a property `->workflow`, side by side with ordinary properties like `->title` or `->created`. Although I can see it there and I expected to filter only items with workflow state 21, I get a horrid database error when trying to execute the code above. Here is more or less the message I get:

> Column not found: 1054 Column 'node.workflow' unknown in 'where
>   clause'

Any ideas on how I should filter an entity query using a workflow state as filter? Maybe what I am trying to do isn'tpossible and I have to actually run a query using db_query and applying the appropriate joins.

Comment: `workflow` isn't a property (in the sense of an 'entity property') it's a value that the workflow module tacks on to a node object in an implementation of `hook_node_load()`. You either need to run a manual query like you say, or use `addTag()` to add a tag to the query, then use `hook_query_TAG_alter()` to alter the query when it's been converted down to a standard `SelectQuery`. At that point joining the workflow will be easy

Comment: Thanks, Clive, I did it with db_query. In the end, doing it this was simpler... Thks a lot, upvoted your comment...

Comment: Random comment ... I speak/write English and Spanish; and I'm working on Korean now. I've seen Ada code in English/French and lots of stuff in English/Spanish ... it's a poor implementation choice as it makes the code harder to maintain in the future (once you're personally off the project). Code should always be written in 1 (spoken) language.

Comment: @MarcosBuarque - Can you share your db_query example please?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [`EntityFieldQuery::propertyCondition()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3ApropertyCondition/7.x), you can use that method for every database field defined in the `hook_schema()` implementation for the base database table used from the entity.

> **$column**: A column defined in the hook_schema() of the base table of the entity.

The code that effectively handle that is in [`EntityFieldQuery::propertyQuery()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3ApropertyQuery/7.x) which contains the following code.

```
  $entity_type = $this->entityConditions['entity_type']['value'];
  $entity_info = entity_get_info($entity_type);
  if (empty($entity_info['base table'])) {
    throw new EntityFieldQueryException(t('Entity %entity has no base table.', array('%entity' => $entity_type)));
  }
  $base_table = $entity_info['base table'];
  $base_table_schema = drupal_get_schema($base_table);
  $select_query = db_select($base_table);
  $select_query->addExpression(':entity_type', 'entity_type', array(':entity_type' => $entity_type));
  // Process the property conditions.
  foreach ($this->propertyConditions as $property_condition) {
    $this->addCondition($select_query, $base_table . '.' . $property_condition['column'], $property_condition);
  }
```

You could implement [`hook_entity_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_query_alter/7.x), which is invoked before `EntityFieldQuery::propertyQuery()` is called, and which (by default) it's the [`EntityFieldQuery::executeCallback`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/property/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AexecuteCallback/7.x) callback, the same callback `hook_entity_query_alter()` is suggested to change. Using your own callback, you could make a join with the tables the Workflow module is using.